# Running Jenkins in a Docker Container

Tags: nginx, jenkins, docker

Im trying to get some hands on experience in Jenkins and wanted to run it in a docker container. I was following the tutorial [here](https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/putting-jenkins-docker-container). I have docker installed on my machine and using Kitematic I launched the official Jenkins docker image (tag: latest) using:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins
```

However once the container is setup when I go to `192.168.99.100:8080` (`192.168.99.100` is my docker-machine ip) it shows the default `nginx` page. `192.168.99.100:8080/jenkins` shows

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /jenkins. Reason:

    Not Found
```

The weird part is that kitmatic shows a web preview of the running container and shows jenkins up and running fine, but how do I access it via the browser????[image]

**EDIT :** Just tried docker run -p 8082:8080 jenkins. and it works i.e. I can see the jenkins landing page. Whaaaa.. ?

Comment: what do your JENKINS_OPTS environment variable look like?  is a --prefix set?

Comment: I havent gotten that far.  I am still stuck in step 4A in the link. I cant seem to get to jenkins from my browser and all the tutorials out there seem to have no issues after running `docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=jenkins-master -d jenkins`

Comment: try localhost:8080

Comment: Ive already tried it. `Site cant be reached`

Comment: You see a default `nginx` page? There's no `nginx` in that tutorial?

Comment: Exactly what I cant figure out too. The official jenkins docker file dsnt mention nginx anywhere yet I see an nginx page

Comment: did you click the arrow out of the box icon in kitematic above the preview?

Comment: Yup, leads to `192.168.99.100:8080` which is the `welcome to nginx` page

Answer (score 0):

See if the port 8080 is already taken by another application. it's not allocating this port because it's taken - that is why it can't reach Jenkins. try looking here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-display-open-ports-owner.html

Comment: `8080` is unlisted when I do `lsof -i`. However when I map the container and host ports using `-p 8080:8080` I cant get to jenkins, when I do `<any other port>:8080` it works fine i.e. I can get to jenkins using `192.168.99.100:chosenport`

Comment: So it might be another service inside your Docker container, and not the host, that is running on that port? which Docker image you're using? unfortunately I can't look at it now, but I'll check the tutorial and see what is running :)

Comment: I am using the official jenkins image hosted on the docker hub - https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/a0f92a484d8194c143f22b8dcfa479aaa85eaceb/Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you. Ill try and figure out the issue in the meantime